# Create dataset based on condition

Tags: r

I have dataset new with variable a b and c

```
a          b     c
hdjfh      434   876
sdfdsf     34    98
gfdsdfdsf  534   672 
rsdfdsf    65    87
gsdfdsf    67    54
vbvnn      98    09
gkhjgfk    100   768
rknfg      78    3546
```

i want to create two datatsets such that dataset new1 need to satisfy condition b >110 or c >110. second dataset new2 will have records that are not satisfied by the condition b >110 or c >110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign the two data sets to new variables, you can do this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('hdjfh','sdfdsf','gfdsdfdsf','rsdfdsf','gsdfdsf','vbvnn','gkhjgfk','rknfg'),b=c(434L,34L,534L,65L,67L,98L,100L,78L),c=c(876L,98L,672L,87L,54L,9L,768L,3546L),stringsAsFactors=F);
cond <- df$b>110|df$c>110;
new1 <- df[cond,];
new2 <- df[!cond,];
new1;
##           a   b    c
## 1     hdjfh 434  876
## 3 gfdsdfdsf 534  672
## 7   gkhjgfk 100  768
## 8     rknfg  78 3546
new2;
##         a  b  c
## 2  sdfdsf 34 98
## 4 rsdfdsf 65 87
## 5 gsdfdsf 67 54
## 6   vbvnn 98  9
```

---

Another option is to use [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) to get a list:

```
split(df,df$b>110|df$c>110);
## $`FALSE`
##         a  b  c
## 2  sdfdsf 34 98
## 4 rsdfdsf 65 87
## 5 gsdfdsf 67 54
## 6   vbvnn 98  9
##
## $`TRUE`
##           a   b    c
## 1     hdjfh 434  876
## 3 gfdsdfdsf 534  672
## 7   gkhjgfk 100  768
## 8     rknfg  78 3546
##
```